# Two Digital Lowpass Filters not correctly implemented in Python

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing, windowing, lowpass-filter

I'm trying to implement 2 lowpass filters and see the difference between them from plots( one FIR filter that needs to be designed with the Hann window method and an IIR filter using Chebyshev type I). The problem is that I can't make 2 correct plots to see the difference between them and I don't know exactly if they are correctly implemented...I have fc1,fc2, ft, rp and rs as parameters. Here it's my python code:

```
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import scipy.signal as signal
        import numpy as np

        def plotInTime(x,fs):
            t=np.arange(0,np.size(x,0)/fs,1/fs)
            plt.figure()
            plt.plot(t,x)
            plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
            plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
            plt.grid(True)

def plotInFrequency(x,fs):
    N=int(np.size(x,0)/2)
    if np.size(x,0)==1:
    X=np.fft.fft(x,axis=1)
    else:
    X=np.fft.fft(x,axis=0)
    X=np.abs(X)
    X=X[:N]
    f=np.arange(0,fs/2,fs/2/N)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(f,X)
    plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
    plt.grid(True)


    #main driver code
        fs, x = myDSP.readWav('Ring05c.wav') #is 22050
        plotInTime(x,fs)
        plt.title('Original Signal')
        plotInFrequency(x,fs)
        plt.title('Spectrum for the Original Signal')

        fc1=1200
        fc2=3000
        fc= np.arange(fc1,fc2+1)
        ft=150
        rp=0.1
        rs=40
        t = np.linspace(-1, 1, 201)
        #x = (np.sin(2*np.pi*0.75*t*(1-t) + 2.1)+0.1*np.sin(2*np.pi*1.25*t + 1) +0.18*np.cos(2*np.pi*3.85*t))
        wp=(fc-ft/2)/(fs/2)
        wp = wp[0]
        ws=(fc+ft/2)/(fs/2)
        ws = ws[0]
        L, Wn = signal.cheb1ord(wp,ws, rp, rs);
        b, a = signal.cheby1(L, rp, Wn,'low')
        f,H=signal.freqz(b,a,worN=256,plot=None,fs=fs)    

        y=signal.lfilter(b,a,x,axis=0)
        plotInTime(y,fs)
        plt.title('Filtered Cheby1 Signal')

        plotInFrequency(y,fs)
        plt.title('Spectrum for the Filtered Cheby1 Signal')
        y=y.astype('int16')

        w_fir = signal.firwin(65, fc/(fs/2), window='hann')
    [w,h] = signal.freqz(w_fir)
    plt.plot(w, 20*np.log10(abs(h)))
    plt.plot(w, np.angle(h))
```

[image: plot difference]